# How do I show metering values in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'm trying to make an app that meters room noise levels.   How do I do this?

I've tried using avrecorder to enable metering but when I try to run my app, it says both the average and peak powers are -160 which is complete silence

This is my func to get update the meter

```
func micLevels() {
    recorder.updateMeters()
    print("meters should be updated")
    self.meteringLabel.text = String(recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))
}
```

The metering label.text is -160 no matter what.  I am calling this func with an NSTimer

Comment: EDIT: the func return is commented out

Comment: Don't you need to be recording to get the power?

Answer (score 0):

Try update text in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.meteringLabel.text = String(recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))
});
```